# How to print hidden text in python selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

[image]

[image]

In the 1st image the red call button after being clicked displays a phone number which is highlighted in yellow in the 2nd picture which needs to be scraped

```
def dealer_info():
    for link in links:
        print('link: ', link)
        driver.get(link)

        div = driver.find_element_by_class_name('seller-details-name')
        dealer_name = div.find_element_by_tag_name('h3').text
        print(dealer_name)

        button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]')))
        button.click()
        phone_no = driver.find_element_by_class_name('showphone').text
        print(phone_no)
```

But it does not print the phone number.
https://www.motortrader.com.my/usedcar/21052000063/2010-bmw-5-series-523i-f10-ckd-8-speeds-direct-1-owner-full-service/index.html

Comment: Please upvote also if it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use .

```
    phone_no = driver.find_element_by_class_name('showphone').get_attribute("textContent")
    print(phone_no)
```

text will check for isDisplayed textContent will display the text no matter if its displayed or not

Answer (score 0):

You can get the phone number even without clicking on that button.

```
phone_no = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.right-column-call-listing a.showphone').get_attribute("textContent")
print(phone_no)
```

BTW it's strongly not recommended to use absolute XPaths / CSS selectors. they are very unstable.
F.e. for that button instead of

```
'/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]'
```

you could use css selector:

```
div.right-column-call-listing a.btn-call
```

or  XPath:

```
//div[contains(@class,'right-column-call-listing')]//a[contains(@class,'btn-call')]
```

Comment: Its still not printing the phone number

Comment: I hope you removed `        button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]')))
        button.click()` ?

Comment: And there is enough delay before `phone_no = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.right-column-call-listing a.showphone').text` command?

Comment: i dont think your solution is going to work

Comment: See the updated answer. use `.get_attribute("textContent")` instead of `.text`